# Flutter how to dynamically get the height of my page and my Listview.Builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm wondering how to get the height of my page dynamically with a Listview.Builder()` inside. This is my page tree:

This is my **News.dart**

```
return SafeArea(
      child: Scrollbar(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 5,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Column(
...
```

Later on we have the `Listview.Builder()`

```
Expanded(child: Consumer<Model>(
                          builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: list.length,
                          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
                              ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                            value: list[index],
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                              },
                              child: Item(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      })),
```

Now below my `SingleChildScrollView()` I have a Container with height of MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 5, I want to have my complete Screen height dynamic. If I remove the height value, I'm getting the render layout error because there is no parent defining a size. This Page here is Part of a TabbarNavigation and this is the content.

Can anybody tell me how to get the dynamic height of the `ListView.Builder()` ?

EDIT:

The following is my Tabbar where I define the pages inside the tabbar. One of them is my **News.dart**

**This is the Tabbar.dart:**

```
final List<Widget> _pages = [
    NewsScreen(),
    TrendScreen(),
    OtherScreen(),
  ];    


    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: _pages[provider.currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: provider.currentIndex != 2
          ? Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
              CustomWidget(),
              BottomNavigationBar(
                onTap: _selectPage,
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                unselectedItemColor: Color.fromRGBO(130, 130, 130, 1),
                selectedItemColor: Color.fromRGBO(236, 37, 105, 1),
                selectedFontSize: 10,
                iconSize: 22,
                currentIndex: provider.currentIndex,
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    title: Text(
                      'home',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.star),
                    title: Text(
                      'News',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                    title: Text('other',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10,
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ])
          : null,
    );
  }
```

Comment: i have no idea why do you need a `SingleChildScrollView` and `ListView` inside - why not to use a `CustomScrollView` and get rid of those problems with height / physics etc?

Comment: Could you provide me an example with Scaffold, some elements and Listview, which is in total higher than the device size height? I dont know a better way doing it to be honest so yeah, show me so i can improve myself :D

Comment: `CustomScrollView(slivers: [SliverToBoxAdapter(...), SliverList(...)])`

Comment: Thank you this made it for me! @pskink

Comment: sure, your welcome, now its much more simple. isnt it?

Comment: This is great, im using list with SliverList now and Containers, Rows and Columns with SliverToBoxAdapter, padding and sizedbox. is this he correct way doing it? Seems good for now

Comment: sure, you can use one `SliverToBoxAdapter` with `Column` as a child but of course you could use mulriple `SliverToBoxAdapter`s too - but the first option is more practical

Comment: great, this is an awesome way to have dynamice heights for every device height, when you working with mediaquery of size width for width, you are good to go for all device sizes

Comment: yep, that's why i said *"[...] and get rid of those problems with height / physics etc"* in my first comment ;-)

Comment: yes, thank you very much for teaching me this, its a great and efficient way working with this approach!

Comment: btw, check https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f - it explains `SliverPersistentHeader` and other slivers

Comment: btw 2, if you want "animated" version of `SliverToBoxAdapter` check [SliverTransformer](https://gist.github.com/pskink/d9775e4dc8bbc5586070229760106031) - it contains `main()` method so you can see how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to @pskink !!

Working with `CustomScrollView()` instead of `SingleChildScrollView()`, `SliverToBoxAdapter()` and `SliverList()` made everything work like charm!

```
return SafeArea(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          // Place sliver widgets here
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 30, 25, 20),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 299,
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
...
```

And a list example:

```
SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (ctx, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: list[index],
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {}),
childCount: rrr.length,
          )),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the "Flex" property of the already used `Expanded()` widget.
first remove the Container at the Top.

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Scrollbar(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
```

...

and then,

Column(

```
children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
       flex : 1,
       child: Consumer<Model>(
           builder: (context, myModel, child) {
             return ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
                    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                      value: list[index],
                      child: GestureDetector(
                         onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                            },
                         child: Item(),
                        ),
                      ),
                   ;
    })),
 ]),
```

API Docs : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Flutter Widget of the Week : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo

Comment: Thank you, we are coming closer, your code makes it work, if the SingleChildScrollView is removed. But I need to scroll the page. How can we obtain this? I Posted my Tabbar file too. Maybe this is also important.

Comment: what do you mean by scrolling the page? is the page has more widgets and is heighter than the device screen?

Comment: Exactly. The page has more widgets and is heighter than device size screen. And my ListViewBuilder does have a different height which depends on how many items are inside.